# The commutation of translation operator with Hamiltonian under electromagnetic field

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, commutator

The book "Introduction to Solid-state" by Madelung gives the commutation of translation operator with Hamiltonian under an electromagnetic field in section 2.2.9 . The Hamiltonian is

$$H=\frac{1}{2 m}(p+e A)^{2}+V(r)+e E \cdot r$$

It then gives the commutator without proof:

$$\left[T_{R}, H\right]=\left(\xi \cdot R+\frac{e^{2} B^{2}}{2 m} R_{x}^{2}\right) T_{R} \quad \mathrm{w} \mathrm{i} \mathrm{th} \quad \xi=e \boldsymbol{v} \times \boldsymbol{B}+e \boldsymbol{E}+e \dot{\boldsymbol{A}}$$

I failed to work it out. Could anyone please help me?

My derivation is as follows

Inserting $\mathbf{A}=(0,Bx,0)$ into the Hamiltonian, we have:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
H &=\frac{1}{2 m}(\mathbf{p}+e \mathbf{A})^{2}+V(r)+e \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r} \\
&=\frac{1}{2 m}(p^2+e\mathbf{p} \cdot  \mathbf{A} +e \mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{p} +e^2A^2)+e \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r}+V(r)\\
&=\frac{1}{2 m}(p^2+ep_yBx + eBxp_y+e^2B^2x^2)+e \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r}+V(r).
\end{array}
$$
Now we consider the commutation of this Hamiltonian with a translation operator $T(\mathbf{R})$, where $\mathbf{R}=(R_x,R_y,R_z)$. We first work out the commutation of $T(\mathbf{R})$ with the term related to the electric field:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
[T(\mathbf{R}),e \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{r}]&=e[T(\mathbf{R}),\mathbf{E}]\cdot\mathbf{r}+e\mathbf{E}\cdot[T(\mathbf{R}),\mathbf{r}]\\
&=e[\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})-\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})]T(\mathbf{R})+e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R}T(\mathbf{R})\\
&=e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R}T(\mathbf{R}).
\end{array}
$$
Then we go to the terms related to the magnetic field, we first pay attention to the term linearly dependent to the magnetic field:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
[T(\mathbf{R}),e p_yBx]&=ep_yB[T(\mathbf{R}),x]\\
&=ep_yBR_xT(\mathbf{R}).
\end{array}
$$
We then pay attention to the terms quadratically dependent to the magnetic field:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
[T(\mathbf{R}),e^2 B^2x^2]&=e B^2[T(\mathbf{R}),x^2]\\
&=e^2B^2[T(\mathbf{R}),x^2]\\
&=e^2B^2{x[T(\mathbf{R}),x]+[T(\mathbf{R}),x]x}\\
&=e^2B^2[xR_xT(\mathbf{R})+R_xT(\mathbf{R})x]\\
&=e^2B^2[xR_xT(\mathbf{R})+R_xxT(\mathbf{R})++R^2_xT(\mathbf{R})]\\
&=2e^2B^2xR_xT(\mathbf{R})+e^2B^2R^2_xT(\mathbf{R}).
\end{array}
$$
In summary, the commutation is

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
[T(\mathbf{R}),H]&=e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R}T(\mathbf{R})+\frac{1}{2m}\{2ep_yBR_xT(\mathbf{R})+2e B^2xR_xT(\mathbf{R})+e B^2R^2_xT(\mathbf{R})\}\\
&=\{e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R}+\frac{1}{m}[ep_yBR_x+ e B^2xR_x]+\frac{1}{2m}e B^2R^2_x\}T(\mathbf{R})\\
&=\{e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R}+ev_yBR_x+\frac{1}{m} (e^2B^2xR_x)+\frac{1}{2m}e^2B^2R^2_x\}T(\mathbf{R})
\end{array}
$$
The final results given in the book is :

$$
\begin{array}{}
\left[T(\mathbf{R}), H\right]&=\left(\xi \cdot \mathbf{R}+\frac{e^{2} B^{2}}{2 m} R_{x}^{2}\right) T(\mathbf{R}) \quad \mathrm{w} \mathrm{i} \mathrm{th} \quad \xi=e \boldsymbol{v} \times \boldsymbol{B}+e \boldsymbol{E}+e \dot{\boldsymbol{A}}\\
&=(eBv_yR_x-eBv_xR_y+\frac{e^{2} B^{2}}{2 m} R_{x}^{2}+e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R}+e\dot{\boldsymbol{A}}\cdot\mathbf{R})T(\mathbf{R})\\
&=(eBv_yR_x+\frac{e^{2} B^{2}}{2 m} R_{x}^{2}+e\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{R})T(\mathbf{R})
\end{array}
$$

Comparing the two results, we find an extral term $\frac{1}{m} (e^2B^2xR_x)$. Is this term left out by the book?

Comment: You need to use an explicit choice of vector potential ${\bf A} = (0,Bx,0)$ as stated in the first paragraph of section 2.1.6. If that hint is not sufficient, you should tell us how far you got and where you are stuck. As an intermediate step, you could try to calculate for $E=0$ or $B=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made some progress following your suggestions, but I only  cpature partly the terms. I was stuck here. Coulg you please help me to have a look at my derivation.  Another question is, is this commutaion only valid for specific expression of vector potential?

Comment: You have to ask yourself: where does $\dot{\bf A}$ come from? For this, see (2.48)-(2.51). Same for $\bf{v} = \dot{\bf{r}}$. Make sure you understand that first. It is easier to first compute $[T_R,\bf{P}]$ where $\bf{P} = \bf{p} + e \bf{A}$.

Comment: Now I am sure that I understand equation (2.48) -(2.51). I realized I misunderstood that $[T(R),p]=0$, but I didn't know to work out this commutation. As you suggested, I computed $[T(R),P]=[T(R),p+eA]$. $[T(R),eA]=(0,eBR_x,0)T(R)$. How to get $[T(R),p]$?

Comment: No, you were correct. The translation operator commutes with the momentum operator. (In fact, the momentum *generates* translations in the sense that the translation is $\exp(i {\bf p} \cdot {\bf R})$.

Now that you have $[T_{\bf R},{\bf P}]$, you can easily calculate $[T_{\bf R},H] =  [T_{\bf R},{\bf P}^2/m]$ for the case that $E=0$. (The potential $V(r)$ is considered invariant under lattice translations.)

Comment: Oh, the missing terms $-eBv_xR_y+e\dot{\mathbf{A}}\cdot \mathbf{R}=0$. Okay, it means I get all terms but get an extral term $\frac{1}{m}e^2B^2xR_x$.Following your guidance, I calculated $[T(\mathbf{R}),P^2]$ and got the same results with my original derivation.

Comment: I am confused about the last term, which is not present in the book.
I paste the derivation here:
$[T(\mathbf{R}),P^2]=[T(\mathbf{R}),P]P+P[T(\mathbf{R}),P]=(0,eBR_x,0)T(\mathbf{R})P+P(0,eBR_x,0)T(\mathbf{R})=e^2B^2R^2_xT(\mathbf{R})+2eBR_xp_yT(\mathbf{R})+2e^2B^2R_xxT(\mathbf{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Hamiltonian (2.131) is

   $$ H = \frac{1}{2m}({\bf p} + e{\bf A})^2 + V({\bf r}) + e {\bf E} \cdot {\bf r}.   \tag{1}$$

   The electric and magnetic fields are constant (homogeneous, so independent of position), and furthermore from section 2.1.6 we take the particular magnetic field ${\bf B} = (0,0,B)$ with choice of vector potential ${\bf A} = (0, x B,0)$.
2. The potential $V({\bf r})$ is considered to be invariant under lattice translations $T_{\bf R}$, so $[T_{\bf R}, V({\bf r})] = 0$.
3. We calculate

   $$ [T_{\bf R},e {\bf E} \cdot {\bf r}] = e {\bf E} \cdot [T_{\bf R},{\bf r}] = e {\bf E} \cdot {\bf R} T_{\bf R}, \tag{2}$$
   where in the first equality we used the fact that the electric field ${\bf E}({\bf r})$ is independent of position, and in the last equality $[T_{\bf R},{\bf r}] = {\bf R} T_{\bf R}$.
4. So the only difficult part is the first term of the Hamiltonian. Using the notation ${\bf P} = {\bf p} + e {\bf A}$, that term is equal to ${\bf P}^2/2m$.

   - We first calculate

     $$ [T_{\bf R}, {\bf P}] = [T_{\bf R}, {\bf p} + e {\bf A}] = e [T_{\bf R}, {\bf A}] = e ({\bf R} \cdot \nabla ) {\bf A} T_{\bf R} \tag{3}$$

     In the second equality we used that the momentum operator ${\bf p}$ is the generator of translations and therefore commutes with the translation operator. In the last equality we used the expansion

     $$ T_{\bf R} f({\bf r}) = f({\bf r} + {\bf R}) = f({\bf r}) + {\bf R} \cdot \nabla f({\bf r}) + \ldots$$
     for any function $f({\bf r})$.
   - We write $[T_{\bf R}, {\bf P}] \equiv {\bf W}T_{\bf R}$ with ${\bf W} \equiv e ({\bf R} \cdot \nabla ) {\bf A}$. Then

     $$\begin{eqnarray} [T_{\bf R}, {\bf P}^2] &=& {\bf P} \cdot [T_{\bf R},{\bf P}] + [T_{\bf R},{\bf P}]\cdot{\bf P} = {\bf P} \cdot{\bf W}T_{\bf R} + {\bf W}\cdot T_{\bf R}{\bf P} \nonumber \\
     &=& 2{\bf P} \cdot{\bf W}T_{\bf R} + {\bf W}\cdot {\bf W} T_{\bf R}. \tag{4} \end{eqnarray}$$
     The first equality is just a commutator identity; we used $ T_{\bf R}{\bf P} = {\bf P}T_{\bf R} + [T_{\bf R},{\bf P}]$ in the last step, as well as ${\bf P} \cdot {\bf W} = {\bf W} \cdot {\bf P}$ (since $\nabla \cdot {\bf A} = 0$).
   - Since ${\bf A}$ only depends on $x$ and not on $y$ and $z$, we have $({\bf R} \cdot \nabla ) {\bf A} = R_x \partial_x {\bf A}$. Using the explicit choice of ${\bf A} = (0,xB,0)$, we see $\partial_x {\bf A} = (0,B,0)$ (remember $B$ is the constant magnetic field amplitude). This leads to the term

   $$\frac{1}{2m} {\bf W}\cdot {\bf W} T_{\bf R} = \frac{e^2  B^2}{2m}R_x^2T_{\bf R}. \tag{5}$$

   - For the final term we need a trick that is also employed in (2.48)-(2.51) in section 2.1.6. First note that ${\bf v} \equiv \dot{\bf r} = \nabla_{\bf p} H = {\bf P}/m$ from (2.48). This is also true for our Hamiltonian (1).

     Then we have $\frac{1}{2m} 2{\bf P} \cdot {\bf W} = e{\bf v} \cdot  ({\bf R} \cdot \nabla) {\bf A}$. The vector notation is getting messy, so let's use index notation: $e v_n R_m \partial_m A_n$.

     We know that ${\bf B} = \nabla \times {\bf A}$, or $B_k = \epsilon_{kmn} \partial_m A_n$. Using an $\epsilon$-identity, one can then obtain $\partial_m A_n = \epsilon_{mnk} B_k + \partial_n A_m$. So we have

     $$v_n R_m \partial_m A_n =  v_n R_m\epsilon_{mnk} B_k + v_n R_m\partial_n A_m. \tag{6} $$

     The first term is in the desired form $({\bf v} \times {\bf B})\cdot {\bf R}$. We need 'the trick' for the second term. We again use that ${\bf A}$ only depends on $x$, so that only $v_x \partial_x$ does not vanish in $v_m \partial_m$. Also, $\partial_x A_m = (0,B,0)_m$. Combining this, we have
     $$v_n \partial_n A_m = (0,v_x B,0)_m = (0,\dot{x} B,0)_m = \partial_t(0,xB,0)_m = \dot{A}_m. \tag{7}$$
     Finally we see that
     $$\frac{1}{2m} 2{\bf P} \cdot {\bf W}T_{\bf R} = e ( {\bf v} \times {\bf B} +   \dot{\bf A}) \cdot {\bf R}T_{\bf R}. \tag{8}$$
5. Together, (2), (5) and (8) lead to the commutator

   $$[T_{\bf R},H] = e ( {\bf v} \times {\bf B} +  {\bf E} +   \dot{\bf A}) \cdot {\bf R}T_{\bf R} + \frac{e^2  B^2}{2m}R_x^2T_{\bf R}. \tag{9}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It is an excellent answer. I found in my derivation, I misunderstood $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{p}$  so that I thought I got an extra term.